# Fix the subplots size rather than have it derived from the main figure size

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I am looking to generate a handful of figures (with the help of a common function).
Some of them would have 2 by 2 subplots, some with 5 by 2 subplots, and some that have 10 by 2 subplots. (since the function parameter may choose to output varying plots)

The challenging aspect I am witnessing is the size of the individual subplots itself.
The subplots (be it 4 or 10 or 20) adjust to the main figure size figsize that is provided at the start of the plotting journey.

Is there a way i can **rather fix the size of the subplots** rather than looking at figsize ?
This way i can automate the plotting for varied subplots and make them look consistent across the multiple figures I am planning to have.

Comment: I do not understand why this question has been marked as 'answered'.

To me it seems the post that is referred to does not actually answer this question. The OP is asking specifically how to resize when you are dealing with *multiple* subplots within a figure. The given answer only works if there is *one* plot.

I am currently facing a similar issue and would certainly like to understand how the given answer in the other post can be applied to this use-case.

Comment: After some experimentation I came up with a solution for my use-case which seems to work pretty well. Perhaps it is useful for you too: [snippet](https://gist.github.com/lcvriend/3aca644ad642a49707f0faa0b7ebc06a).